# VBScript to recursively scrape a local intranet page for links

Tags: csv, vbscript, web-scraping

I've been tasked with identifying all of the many links we have on our team's intranet.  The goal is to declutter (find duplicate links or dead links).

I wrote this script that will go to our page and scrape every link while identifying the file extension.  What I'm not sure how to do is to make this recursive.  Once it goes to our site and scrapes those links, if it finds another URL (such as htm or html) I want it to follow THAT link and scrape the same from there and continue on until every link associated with the initial URL is exhausted.  I'd like it to create a type of hierarchy in the csv such as (example headers):
lvl0_Link_Title,lvl0_File_Type,lvl0_URL,lvl1_Link_Title,lvl1_File_Type,lvl1_URL,lvl2_Link_Title,lvl2_File_Type,lvl2_URL,lvl3_Link...etc.

Obviously, this would end up with a pretty massive csv.  If there is a better/cleaner method to achieve the same, I'm open to it.

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

on error resume next

filename = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\URL_Dump_Oldsite.csv"

'==============================================
'Create headers for CSV
    set output = fso.opentextfile(filename,2,true) 
    output.writeline "Link Title,File Type,URL"
    output.close
'==============================================

IE.Visible = false
IE.Navigate "URL OF OUR INTRANET"
Do While IE.Busy or IE.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.sleep 100: Loop
Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 100: Loop

for each url in ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a")

    if not url.href is nothing then

    ext = mid(url.href,instrrev(url.href,"."))

        set output = fso.opentextfile(filename,8,true) 
        output.writeline replace(url.innertext,","," / ") & "," & ext & ",=HYPERLINK(" & chr(34) & url.href & chr(34) & ")"
        output.close 

    end if

next

'===========================================
'Keyword filter for removal

Dim arrFilter
arrFilter = Array("bakpcweb", _
        "aims", _
        "element", _
        "objid", _
        "nodeid", _
        "objaction", _
        "javascript", _
        "itemtype")

'===========================================
'Delete lines from csv file containing keywords

strFile1 = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\URL_Dump_Oldsite.csv"

Set objFile1 = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile1)

Do Until objFile1.AtEndOfStream

    i = 0

    strLine1 = trim(lcase(objFile1.Readline))

    for a = lbound(arrFilter) to ubound(arrFilter)

        if instr(strLine1,arrFilter(a)) <> 0 then
            i = i + 1
        End If

    next

    if i = 0 then
        strNewContents1 = strNewContents1 & strLine1 & vbCrLf
    end if

Loop

objFile1.Close

Set objFile1 = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile1,2,true)
objFile1.Write strNewContents1
objFile1.Close

'===========================================
'Delete blank lines from csv file

strFile = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\URL_Dump_Oldsite.csv"

Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.Readline
    strLine = Trim(strLine)
    If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
        strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile,2,true)
objFile.Write strNewContents
objFile.Close

'===========================================

'Remove duplicate lines from csv file

Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

strFile = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\URL_Dump_Oldsite.csv"

Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.Readline
    strLine = Trim(strLine)
    If Not objDictionary.Exists(strLine) Then
        objDictionary.Add strLine, strLine
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = fso.opentextfile(strFile,2,true)

For Each strKey in objDictionary.Keys
    objFile.WriteLine strKey
Next

objFile.Close
objDictionary.clearall

'===========================================


wscript.echo "Done!"
ie.quit
wscript.quit
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you were expecting, but it sounds like you're reinventing the wheel here, and with a sub-standard tool. In my experience, I also wouldn't find the lvl0, lvl1 etc. format particularly useful when reporting later.

I would strongly recommend you instead use an existing program to scan your intranet, such as [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) or for a more in-depth analysis, try [Screaming Frog SEO Spider](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) (free version is limited to about 500 pages, as I recall, but you can give it a try). These tools have features to save reports, which should suit your needs.

If that doesn't work for you, please comment or edit your answer to explain why you *must* do this yourself and report in the specified format.

Edit: Here's an example screenshot from the free Xenu program, which lists every resource it tried, its status, links in/out, and type, which can assist with your requirement to report on filetypes. It will also generate full HTML reports if you want stats.

[image: Xenu screenshot]